# Paperback YA novel where protagonists assume ghost's unfinished business is charity clothes drive

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this somewhere in the 1990s, almost certainly as a Young Adult paperback, in English and in the United States. I might have gotten it from the library. There was a ghost that the main characters are trying to put to rest. They manage to figure out the identity of the ghost, a poor girl, and decide that her unfinished business had to do with that she had participated in a charity clothing drive where she had been unfairly cheated out of winning. I seem to recall there was an aspect of personal sacrifice involved, maybe that she added a good deal of her own clothing to pad out her donation, and I have some memory of sewing being involved in it.

Anyhow, the protagonists acquire a large amount of clothing and bring it to her old house (which I think was boarded up and abandoned so they had to pry open an entrance and crawl in) in hopes that it might appease her. Instead, it outrages her and she starts attacking them. I have a memory of them running from room to room as a spinning maelstrom of clothing pursues them. For some reason, I want to say that there was fire involved in her attack too. They had gotten her motivation wrong, and she turned out to have a more malevolent history than they'd assumed.

Outside of that, my memory is blank, but the whole charity clothing drive has stuck with me through the years. I'm 90% certain that it was not a *Fear Street* book. It might have been *Point Horror*; I read a number of those back then.

Comment: Great, more rep for Valorum!

Comment: @Möoz: ^_^ He didn't answer it when it first came out...